# How to implement jump in NavMesh?

Tags: unity, unityscript, navmesh

I want my NavMeshAgent to jump when <kbd>Space</kbd> key is hit.

The Script (*in Unityscript*) I tried is **:**

```
var isJump:boolean=false;

function Update () {

  if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){

     GetComponent.<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>().enabled=false;
     GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().isKinematic=false;
     GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0,400,0);
     isJump=true;

 }
}


 function OnCollisionEnter(col:Collision){

   if(col.gameObject.layer==4 && isJump){

     GetComponent.<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>().enabled=true;
     GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().isKinematic=true;
     isJump=false;
  }

}
```

The ground where the NavMeshAgent stands is in layer 4. But the Agent is not jumping in the first place. But when I don't used the *OnCollisionEnter* function it jumps. But I need some function to return it to the initial state.

I tried a *print("something")* inside *if* statement of *OnCollisionEnter* function and it prints it as soon as I hit <kbd>Space</kbd>. That *if* statement should have executed when the object jumped and collides with the ground.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

### Why it is not working

As you said, the function is called as soon as you hit <kbd>Space</kbd>. That's why it doesn't work because `isKinematic` is then instantly reset to `true` before your character can even start his jump.
You must have another object other than the ground that is in layer 4 and is colliding with the player.

### How to make it work

Instead of using the layer, I would give the Ground object (and any other similar object) a **Tag**, like "Ground" for instance. And use :

```
function OnCollisionEnter(col:Collision){

   if(col.gameObject.tag == "Ground" && isJump){

     GetComponent.<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>().enabled=true;
     GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().isKinematic=true;
     isJump=false;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks......yes I need the NavMesh for sure....I don't want my character to be control by physics when moving around the world ....so kinematic is also necessary i guess....

Comment: and the isKinematic=true should execute when object hits the ground....why its executing even before the jump..

Comment: Okay I gave a wrong answer I guess. Try out what I just wrote and tell me if it works :)

Comment: sorry not working.....and its the same code as mine but you use tag and i used layer...

Comment: Yes but I don't know your game, so this change could be meaningful. What other objects are on layer 4 ?

Comment: Only a plane where there is a cube with NavMeshAgent component...

Comment: I found the solution just hold for sometime (like 0.2 seconds) before setting isJump = true

Comment: Okay, you can delete my answer if you want and post your own as a solution in 2 days :)

Comment: I can't delete I think I don't have enough reputation :(  Why don't you edit your answer

Comment: Because I don't know exactly how you did it and it's not my own answer haha

Answer (score 0):

Just hold for sometime before changing isJump to true.

Here's the edited script **:**

```
 var hold:boolean=true;
 var isJump:boolean=false;
 function Update () {

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){

  gameObject.GetComponent.<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>().enabled=false;

  GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().isKinematic=false;
  GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0,400,0);
  if(hold)
  Hold();

  }
}


function Hold(){
   hold=false;
   yield WaitForSeconds(0.1);
   isJump=true;
   hold=true;
 }

  function OnCollisionEnter(col:Collision){

     if(col.gameObject.layer==4 && isJump){

     GetComponent.<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>().enabled=true;
     GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().isKinematic=true;
     isJump=false;

    }
   }
```